# Returning a callback for centralized handling

Tags: javascript, meteor, coffeescript

In fileA, I can do

```
@someAPI = SomeAPI()
@someAPI.getUser '123'
```

then in fileB

```
class SomeAPI

  constructor: (options = {}) ->
    unless @ instanceof SomeAPI
      return new SomeAPI(options)

  getUser: (id) ->
    someAPI.get 'users/show', { 'id': id }, (err, data, res) ->
      if data
        console.log data.name
```

but is there some way to have the callback returned, so I can do the handling in fileA?

fileA pseudocode

```
...

processUser: (id) ->
  @someAPI.getUser id, (err, data, res) ->
    if data
      console.log data.name

processUser '123'
```

fileB pseudocode

```
...

getUser: (id) ->
  return someAPI.get 'users/show', { 'id': id }, (err, data, res)
```

This is for a Meteor app where fileA is part of the app, fileB part of a package.

Comment: Is this on the client or server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you think the other way around and pass the callback to fileB ?

```
getUser: (id, callback) ->
  return someAPI.get 'users/show', { 'id': id }, callback
```

Then in your app code, pass the callback as an argument to perform result handling locally :

```
processUser: (id) ->
  @someAPI.getUser id, (err, data, res) ->
    if data
      console.log data name
```

This is what you did so I'm not sure I understand your concern.

Comment: Thanks, works great. I'm a newb to callbacks in general so missing some of the basics. ^^

Comment: Except what if the callback structure is different? I.e. if I have to do some tinkering in the getUser method before returning it.

Comment: `getUser` is just a wrapper around some api call which just take parameters and a callback so I'm not sure what tinkering you could reasonably do in `getUser` that wouldn't best take place BEFORE the call to `getUser`, in the api caller context... please edit your question with a clear example if you want a better answer from me.

Comment: I'll make a new question with a clear example since I think your answer covered what I originally asked about.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on the server, you can use fibers to write this in a synchronous fashion. For example, using futures:

```
# fileB
Future = Npm.require("fibers/future")

class SomeAPI
  constructor: # ...
  getUser: (id) ->
    # Create a Future object
    fut = new Future()

    # Fire off an API call; when it finishes we store the result in
    # the Future object
    someAPI.get 'users/show', { 'id': id }, (err, data, res) ->
      if err
        fut.throw(err)
      else
        fut.return([data, res])

    # Wait for the Future to resolve and return the value we stored in it
    return fut.wait()

# Usage in fileA
# This is synchronous. If an error occurred, you will get an exception
[data, res] = @someApi.getUser(id)
console.log(data.name)
```

If you ever want to call out to the API in a Meteor method, you'll probably have to use fibers.